# Does CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem also delete all the node's sub-tree HTREEITEMs

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Does `CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem` also delete all the node's sub-tree `HTREEITEM`s or must I recursively traverse the sub-tree myself and call `DeleteItem` on each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the MFC source code for `CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem`, it does this:

```
_AFXCMN_INLINE BOOL CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem(_In_ HTREEITEM hItem)
{ 
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); 
    return (BOOL)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, TVM_DELETEITEM, 0, (LPARAM)hItem); 
}
```

Now looking at the [documentation of TVM_DELETEITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it says the following (my emphasis):

> Removes an item **and all its children** from a tree-view control

This would imply that recursively deleting *is* unnecessary, but I must admit that I've not tested it - the documentation may be misleading (as it sometimes is). One way to test is to note this line in the documentation:

> The parent window receives a TVN_DELETEITEM notification code when
>   each item is removed.

So, by providing a handler for that message, you could verify that child items are deleted correctly.

Comment: _So, by providing a handler for that message, you could verify that child items are deleted correctly._  I tried this and it does delete all the sub-tree items recursively

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN Docs on CTreeCtrl::DeleteItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdhxwhcx.aspx) where it says `If hitem has the TVI_ROOT value, all items are deleted from the tree view control`, I would infer that it will alo delete sub-nodes...

Comment: I think that works only if the item is at the root level.  If the item is on a child node (eg. you would not specify TVI_ROOT for its handle), then you would need to iterate as the example shows.  I think that's what this answer means.

Comment: I am NOT deleting the root, but a sub-tree of THE tree.  I am doing it recursively right now, but was wondering if I am doing it "the hard way".

Comment: Also, if it DOES delete all the sub-tree items in addition to the specified item, MSDN would have stated simply that it did that, with a possible note that "Hence, if hitem has the TVI_ROOT value, ...".  But since it does not state that for all nodes, I am guessing that it does not delete sub-tree items, and that TVI_ROOT is an exception to the "simple" behavior.

Comment: I have verified this, deleting a treeview item does delete the item and all its children.